# I am struggling trying to convert a Fiscal Year Month column to datetime in Python/Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

After calling

```
import pandas as pd

df_month = pd.read_csv('my file.csv')
```

I have a date column in the data called df_month['month'], however the format sent to me in the csv is in a "fiscal year" format.

For example when I call df_month.month the output is:

| month |
| --- |
| FY19-APR |
| FY19-AUG |
| ... |
| FY21-Mar |

When I try to convert the column to date time I receive an error:

```
test_datecol = df_month.month

test_datecol = pd.to_datetime(test_datecol,dayfirst = False, yearfirst = True, format = '%Y%M')

error:
TypeError: Unrecognized value type: <class 'str'>
ValueError: time data 'FY20-NOV' does not match format '%Y%M' (match)
```

Any guidance or a point in the right direction would be greatly appreciated. Thank you

Comment: Try with `format = 'FY%Y-%b'`?

Comment: Thank You for your quick response. I ran the code you suggested, and I still receive a ValueError: time data 'FY20-NOV' does not match format 'FY%Y-%b' (match)

Comment: Sorry, use lower case `y`: `format = 'FY%y-%b'`.

Comment: The lowercase 'y' worked. That was too simple. Thank you for your help

Comment: Just an FYI if you want to know more on formats : https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior

Comment: @Neeraj I should have started there. Thank you for the reference

Comment: No problem! Happy coding :) @BlaineK

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to post the solution to my problem, thanks to @Quang Hoang

Originally I used this line of code

```
test_datecol = pd.to_datetime(test_datecol,dayfirst = False, yearfirst = True, format = '%Y%M')
```

Solution: In the format parameter use 'FY%y-%b'

```
test_datecol = pd.to_datetime(test_datecol,dayfirst = False, yearfirst = True, format = 'FY%y-%b')
```

Thanks again to everyone for your help.